# How do I use different grunt-contrib-less options on different files

Tags: javascript, less, gruntjs

I want to use grunt-contrib-less in my Grunt file, but I want some files to be compressed with 'yuicompress' but others I want to keep as is. How do I tell grunt-contrib-less to use different options on different files?

Comment: Use various targets + `grunt-contrib-concat`. There'll be no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify which files you want to go through which process, and create different targets within the config;

for example to have foo.less use the standard options, and bar.less to use the yuicompress option you would configure it like so in the gruntfile:

```
less: {
  standard: {
    files: {
      "output/path/foo.css": "src/path/foo.less"
    }
  },
  yui: {
    options: {
      yuicompress: true
    },
    files: {
      "output/path/bar.css": "src/path/bar.less"
    }
  }
}
```

running `grunt less` in the terminal will run both targets, or you can specify just one like: `grunt less:yui`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it.